# Sphinx build without setup.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setuptools

Use of static metadata is currently [recommended](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata). Sphinx's [BuildDoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/setuptools.html) (`setuptools` and `distutils` integration) allows to build the docs using `python setup.py build_sphinx`. Does this mean `setup.py` file needs to be present still? Or is there a way to trigger sphinx build by having only `setup.cfg`? The static metadata file is even mentioned in Sphinx's docs but the build examples are all with the dynamic metadata.

Comment: If you use BuildDoc, yes; else you can use [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html).

Comment: But `sphinx-build` does not parse `setup.cfg` as far as I can tell. You see, I wanted to gather all the common parameters for the app and the docs, e.g. version number, in one place. So I turned to BuildDoc.

Comment: Why not use `conf.py`?

Comment: I guess I could if I were to use `setup.py`, but how would I parse `conf.py` from `setup.cfg`?